# Configure the git commit used for Change Markers

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Usually seeing the differences between the last commit (HEAD) and the working tree is what I'd like, but from time to time I'd like to see change markers that indicate changes between the working tree and one or two commits ago.

Is it possible to choose or configure the commit that is used to generate the [Change Markers](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-change-markers-to-view-and-navigate-through-changes-in-the-editor.html) shown in the editor gutter?

Comment: *"since the most recent synchronization with the repository"* - as no configuration is mentioned, I'd assume there isn't any.